# how to disable file transfert in tightvnc?

Tags: file-transfer, vnc

Having tested all the VNC servers I found, I choosed Tightvnc.
But it actually has one more feature that I need : file transfert.
How can I disable it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code of 2.02, there is a checkbox labeled "Enable file transfers" which controls this parameter for you. I don't run Windows to check but it should be there in the Server configuration dialog, following the source confirms it's fully enabled from dialog box down into the actual file transfer request handler code.

Comment: It looks good. At first I was afraid that the client can do that too making it useless, but it seems to be protected by a password which is good enough for me. Thanks !